# Heroes VII memory usage > 8Gb issue

Tags: technical-issues, might-and-magic-heroes-7

When I try to run Heroes VII on My PC it runs out of physical memory during game load (even before it gets to the game main menu) and windows stop responding until finally crash.

Sys: intel i7 / 8Gb Ram / windows 7

What can be done to reduce the memory used?

Comment: Strange; even the recommended is only 6 gigs.  Where'd you get the game from?

Comment: I got it from steam.